# A pointer type static field's value is displayed as zero 0x0 by the debugger while it actually has a valid value

Tags: c#, pointers, visual-studio-2012, unsafe, intptr

I came across this behaviour while trying to access the value of a struct's static field with type `uint*`

While debugging, watch window shows the static field `StaticBitMask`'s value as zero, but actually (and as expected) it is a valid pointer, and `Console.WriteLine()` prints it, as can be seen in the console output below:

```
Pointers:
-----------------
Static bitmask pointer: 0x706790
Instance bitmask pointer: 0x708A20

Values:
-----------------
Static bitmask pointer val: 0xFFFFFFFF
Instance bitmask pointer val: 0xFFFFFFFF
```

This inconsistent behaviour is not observed with the fixed instance fields. For those, the actual value can be seen in the watch window and is printed out.

[image: Watch Window]

Why is this happening? I know that it is not a showstopper by the way, but why, one wonder.

Also, what will the consequences of having a static field with a pointer type in a struct? Since it cannot be marked as `fixed`, is it possible that it may be moved around buy GC anytime?

Here is the source code which you can directly run as a console application to reproduce the problem.

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public unsafe struct UIntBitMask
{
    private static int uintNumberOfBits = sizeof(uint) * 0x8;

    public static uint* StaticBitMask;

    public fixed uint InstanceBitMask[1024]; // uintNumberOfBits * uintNumberOfBits = 32 * 32 = 1024

    public UIntBitMask(bool fillBitMask)
    {
        GetUnmanagedBitMask();
    }

    static UIntBitMask()
    {
        IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(uintNumberOfBits * uintNumberOfBits * sizeof(uint));
        StaticBitMask = (uint*)pointer.ToPointer();
        for (int i = 0; i < uintNumberOfBits; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < uintNumberOfBits; j++)
                ((uint*)&StaticBitMask[i])[j] = ((uint.MaxValue >> (uintNumberOfBits - j)) << i);
    }

    private void GetUnmanagedBitMask()
    {
        fixed (uint* structPointer = InstanceBitMask)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < uintNumberOfBits; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < uintNumberOfBits; j++)
                    ((uint*)&structPointer[i])[j] = ((uint.MaxValue >> (uintNumberOfBits - j)) << i);
        }
    }
}

public class PointerTypeStaticFieldLab
{
    static unsafe void Main()
    {
        UIntBitMask instance = new UIntBitMask(true);
        Console.WriteLine("Pointers:");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Static bitmask pointer: 0x{0:X}", new IntPtr(UIntBitMask.StaticBitMask).ToInt64());
        Console.WriteLine("Instance bitmask pointer: 0x{0:X}", new IntPtr(instance.InstanceBitMask).ToInt64());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Values:");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Static bitmask pointer val: 0x{0:X}", UIntBitMask.StaticBitMask[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance bitmask pointer val: 0x{0:X}", instance.InstanceBitMask[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the generated native code? I wouldn't be surprised at all to find that the debugger is correctly showing you exactly what's going on, and that the `StaticBitMask` field's usage was optimized out of the class. Does the behavior change depending on whether you compile Debug vs Release, or on x86 vs x64?

Comment: I don't understand the other question: _"is it possible that it may be moved around buy GC anytime"_ -- would it even matter if the _field_ itself moved? What you care about is its _value_, right? The memory block allocated by `AllocHGlobal()` is not itself moveable, so the pointer value you store in the field should remain valid.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I will check the generated IL. I check the watch window with a debug build. If you reproduce the issue, you will see that when the execution is at the Console.WriteLine for the static variable, the watch window, the quick watch window and the value tooltip (when hovering over the variable) always show the value as 0x00000000 and when stepped over, the actual value is printed out to the std out.

Comment: _"I will check the generated IL"_ -- check the _native_ code, not the IL. The C# compiler does some optimizations, but the JITter is responsible for the more aggressive ones.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think you are right with your second comment. Even if the static field is moved which contains only an address, it's value (the memory address returned by HAllocGlobal()) is not affected, thanks

Comment: @PeterDuniho x64 release build, same behaviour.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, for what it's worth, the debugger is emitting the address of the fixed data. I have a related q here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044890/why-doesnt-the-vs-2015-debug-visualizer-work-on-this-unsafe-struct

Comment: @OguzOzgul, a very reasonable answer was posted in a comment to my question referenced above

Comment: Dear new debugging engine victims - oh we poor low level enthusiastics - :) @Clay's question has the answer.

Comment: Besides, I want to confess that I'd failed to invoke the Occam's Razor in this case, which would have (and does now) pointed the debugger instantly. Something is wrong during debugging, but not on the run-time, therefore the simplest explanation is, something is wrong with the debugger. (Had I done that, still, without finding that switch in the options, I would have feared that it would end up in something being wrong between my keyboard and my chair)